# Download text file from server using cron job and php

Tags: php, cron

I'm looking for a script you can auto download file from one server and upload to a database using php and cron jobs. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks.

Comment: It's much more easier to write your own cURL  script depending on your needs.

Comment: im not overly familiar with curl, ill google and see what i get and repost if find anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `ftp` and php that functionality : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

**Prove of Concept**

```
$remoteUrl = "http://balabla/abc.pdf" ; // to remote file
$localTemp = "temp" ; // Temp directory 
$file = 'somefile.txt';
$ftpServer = "";
$ftpUsername = "";
$ftpPassword = "" ;
$serverPath = 'data/upload/'; // this most exist on your the server you are uploading to

//Get Remote FIle 
$localFile = $localTemp . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($remoteUrl);
file_put_contents($fileName, file_get_contents($remoteUrl));


//Upload The File 

$connID = ftp_connect($ftpServer);
$loginID = ftp_login($connID, $ftpUsername, $ftpPassword);

if(!$connID || !$loginID)
{
    die("Can't Connect to FTP");
}

ftp_chdir($connID, $serverPath); //Change Directory 

if (ftp_put($connID, $localFile, basename($localFile), FTP_BINARY )) {
    echo "successfully uploaded $localFile\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $localFile\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($connID);
```

I hope it helps

Comment: thanks for this but i keep getting this error message Warning: ftp_get(): Opening data channel for file transfer.

Comment: Can you put for implementation in pastbin let me see

Comment: have tried a passive connection to ftp using ftp_pasv($conn_id,true); and this does not work and changed file permissions but again this has had no effect either

Comment: tinkered with permissions again and all sorted thanks great ansswer!